# How to pull from remote 'A' to remote 'B' in Git

Tags: windows, command-line, git

I have 2 remote branches: `origin/master` and `origin/my_123` - `my_123` was branched off of `master` at some point but is now behind. I'd like to pull from `master` into `my_123` so that `my_123` is in sync with `master` before pushing some changes to it.

No commits were made to `my_123` after it was branched from `master`, so this should be a straight operation with no conflicts.

I'd like to know what would be the `git` command line for this - I did a lot of googling but I couldn't find the answer (or I overlooked it) and the `git pull` documentation is cryptic at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can visualize the branch like this:

```
     A--B--C--D--E--F
     ^              ^
     |              |
   my_123         master
origin/my_123  origin/master
```

You can just **fast-forward** the branch to `master`.

It will be seen like this.

```
     A--B--C--D--E--F
     ^              ^
     |              |
 origin/my_123    master
                  my_123
             origin/master
```

After that you can just push `my_123` to `origin`, so it looks like.

```
     A--B--C--D--E--F
                    ^
                    |
                  master
                  my_123
             origin/master
             origin/my_123
```

the operations will be involving these:

```
$ git checkout my_123
$ git merge master
$ git push origin my_123
```

*(by git's default configuration, merging is fast-forward enabled (i.e, no merge commit is created), if there is no conflict found)*